# Co-worker refuses to do my work during my notice

Tags: colleagues, notice-period

I am currently serving notice, in a reputed MNC, where the notice period is said to be streamlined and smooth. My task was to handle the client and do minimal tasks, while a co-worker was to handle the rest of the work without knowledge of the client (for a limited time). Out of 3 months, only 1 month remains.

So, I asked my manager to introduce this co-worker to the client, as my replacement. He did. Now, his interview has been scheduled with the client.

His interview was scheduled on Tuesday. Now, this fellow has been working in the same skill set that client wants for the last 1.5 years. But he refuses to do his part of the work, citing interview preparations. Since I understand the tension of interviews, I said that I can manage one day, i.e. Friday, then he will have two days in hand to prepare (Weekends). I also informed him that he has to work for the first half (first 4 hours) on Monday, after which I will manage the rest. The problem with handling his work is, I need to go through the entire documentation (a lot of it) to get the gist of his work, and only then start working. We do not have so much time for that. Even then I informed him that I will help him with his work, but still he has to do his assigned work.

Even then, he is not willing to work. He tells me that he will complain to my manager if I do not work in my notice period. But, I am doing my part of the work. He isn't doing his.

How do I handle this colleague? Am I wrong in this situation, and should I do his work, until his interview is completed?

Comment: Your assumption that he should spend his weekend preparing is quite frankly insulting, unless he is contracted to work weekends.

Comment: @Dom He has to prepare, whether he does it on weekends or not. I too, didn't want to push him for weekends, but that should be his problem, not mine.

Comment: Location? Given the 3-month notice period, I might guess this is India, and you need management to give you one of those release letters, which coworkers may think they can blackmail you over. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Yes, I am from India, but it is not about release letter. Since I am in MNC , release letter is automated. One need not beg for the same, at least in my company. The release letter, may however be delayed, which is what the co-worker threatens

Comment: Thanks. To clarify: It's at least a little bit about the release letter (being delayed)?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Not really. I meant that, in case during notice, a person takes leave , the release may be extended. So, my co-worker is threatening that, if I dont do that work, he will complain to my manager, that I am taking unofficial leave, and it will be delayed

Comment: Do you think this is a legitimate threat, or not?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins No idea.

Comment: As someone not familiar with the Indian system, what is the context/content of this interview?  Your colleague is already working for your company, and the company is contracting with the client, why does the client need to interview your colleague?

Comment: @Ertai87 Client's call

Comment: MNC means "a multinational company"

Answer (score 38):

**This is not your problem, this is your manager's problem**

You're leaving, so anything your colleague says to your manager shouldn't matter. However, if you want to keep on your manager's good side, then approach this as any other interpersonal workplace conflict:

- Keep notes of the work you do
- Keep notes of work your colleague has agreed to do (with email evidence, preferably)
- Present this to your manager as part of regular scheduled meetings

Keep this factual. Do not include any opinions on what your colleague should have done or should have been doing, and don't pass judgement on what is happening. Simply present the facts of what you have done and what your colleague has agreed to do. Anything which is not covered by either of those two things should be the responsibility of your manager.

It's only a month to go so you won't have to keep this up long. Then it won't be something you're involved with anyway.

Answer (score 11):

> He tells me that he will complain to my manager if I do not work in my notice period.

Take it to your manager first and discuss the problem. It's up to the manager to find a solution if there is any conflict.

The main issue is you are trying to organise things without the authority to override your colleague. This would be fine if they cooperated, but since they are not, then it's the managers problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a managerial problem for the manager to fixed. Since you are on a notice period and stay on the manager's good side as well, you need to handle it carefully. You said it is your co worker, please try to make it clear that you are on your notice period and he should learn to acclimatize to the job, since you wouldn't be there for long.